# Develop iOS app for 64bit

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-64bit

After creating project or workspace in xcode do I need to explicitly set the app for 64bit environment in anywhere in project settings?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: New projects created with Xcode 8 or 9 are already setup to support 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 11 doesn't support 32-bit. By default Xcode sets 64-bit.

In Xcode 8 and below, make sure you add `arm64` to **Valid Architectures** and select **Standard Architectures**.

[image: architecture configuration in Xcode]

Comment: Thanks for reaching me, What are armv7 and armv7s?

Comment: Xcode 9 supports 32-bit. It's iOS 11 that doesn't support 32-bit, not Xcode. If your app has a deployment target of iOS 10 or earlier, you can setup your app to support both 32 and 64-bit.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale armv7s is the architecture of the A6 processor in the iPhone 5, armv7 is the processor instruction set used in the iPhone 3GS till iPhone5

Comment: as @rmaddy stated you can build for 32-bit by targeting iOS <= 10, but you won't be able to publish that app on the iTunes app store...just wanted to add that for future readers.  I could be wrong, but I am 95% sure.

Comment: @JacobBoyd You can publish such apps on the store. Why wouldn't you be able to? All of my apps support iOS 8 and later. All of those apps work through iOS 11. All of those apps support both 32 and 64 bit. The only thing Apple doesn't allow (any more) are 32-bit only apps. All apps must support 64-bit. Optionally they can support 32-bit if your app's Deployment target is iOS 10 or earlier.

Comment: o0o ok, I knew I read an article about Apple not supporting 32-bit on the store anymore, but allowing a app that supports both; makes sense! thanks @rmaddy !

Answer (score 0):

Newly created projects in XCode will automatically support the current (64 bit) architecture.

Comment: That’s true, since iOS 11 only allows 64 Bit applications all projects created in xCode are 64 Bit compatible projects (Actually since Xcode 8 I believe).